# Is there are deb package with python3.5 for arm architecture?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, python-3.5, deb, orange-pi

Is there are deb package with python3.5 for arm arch?
Needs that to install on Raspberry Pi(raspbian) and Orange PI(ubuntu) devices. 
I tried to compile from the sources but faced with absent libs like math or setuptools. So I can not to consider this option

Answer (score 0):

for pi raspbian you can try to swap to [stretch](https://linuxconfig.org/raspbian-gnu-linux-upgrade-from-jessie-to-raspbian-stretch-9)